# Excell to R for automated (recurrent) assay

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I would like to make an automated process in which I copy a set of numbers from Excel (three columns and nine rows) and then paste them in R and have a data.frame or a table. When I copy the numbers from Excel and paste them in R it looks like this:

```
0.305   0.29    0.285

0.303   0.292   0.288

0.44    0.421   0.416

0.578   0.616   0.542

0.842   0.918   0.797

1.088   1.105   1.06

1.294   1.325   1.26

1.79    1.755   1.895

2.097   2.196   2.19
```

The main problem I see is that I would have to add commas after each number and `c()` before the first number. Then I would have to create a data.frame specifying three columns and nine rows and that is not very fats.

Comment: Consider using the “readxl” package to import directly from the Excel file.

Comment: You should not copy-paste data from excel to R. Import the data in R from excel. There are packages available to help you do that.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to stick to a copy+paste approach, you might consider to use the DataEditR package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataEditR/vignettes/DataEditR.html